# SQL order by integer within a string

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a string that my result is sorting by.  It is composed of a room number, resident name, and a few other fields.

Example:

```
460, Bob Jones, ......
5, John Doe, .....
```

The problem is, when I order this way, it puts large numbers that begin with a small number ahead of the small numbers that begin with a large one (ie, 460 is placed before 5).  How can I have sql process the entire integer in the string and sort based on the entire number, not just the first digit value?

Comment: A string is not an integer and it'll sort numbers as 1,10,11,2,20,3,4,44,etc if they are stored as a string (varchar)...    First comment is to reconsider your database use, storing strings with integer values mixed with data is horrid practice.  If database structure is outside of your scope...using substrings you can pick out the integer before the first comma, convert to an integer, and sort on that.  What database are you on?  String functions vary between them

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting the initial part of the string to a number.  However, this depends on the database.  For instance, in MySQL, you can convert the value to an integer just by adding `+ 0`:

```
order by string + 0
```

In other databases, you would need to part up to the comma and do a conversion.  For instance, in SQL Server:

```
order by cast(left(string, charindex(',', string) - 1) as int)
```